# JQuery Autocomplete Not Working After Following Example

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-autocomplete

So I was trying to follow along multiple examples and I can't get it to work.  I tried it in JSFiddle, and my own browser and nothing is working!  I am trying to do an autocomplete field for drugs available from different websited.

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var drugs = ["Acepromazine (PromAce, Aceproject)", "Acetaminophen (Tylenol)",
        "Acetazolamide (Diamox, Dazamide)", "Acetylcysteine (Mucomyst)", 
        "Acetylsalicylic Acid (Aspirin)", 
        "Activated Charcoal (Toxiban, Liqui-Char, UAA Gel)", "Acyclovir (Zovirax)",
        "Albuterol (Proventil, Volmax, Ventolin)", "Allopurinol (Zyloprim)",
        "Alprazolam (Xanax)", "Amikacin (Amiglyde-V)", "Aminopentamide (Centrine)",
"Aminophylline",
"Amitraz (Mitaban, Preventic)",
"Amitriptyline HCl (Elavil)",
"Amlodipine Besylate (Norvasc)",
"Amoxicillin",
"Amoxicillin and Clavulanate (Clavamox)",
"Amphetamines",
"Amphotericin B",
"Ampicillin (Polyflex)",
"Antibiotic with Steroid Eye Medication",
"Apomorphine",
"Bismuth Subsalicylate (Pepto-Bismol)",
"Brinzolamide (Azopt)",
"Bromides",
"Buprenorphine (Buprenex)",
"Burow's Solution",
"Buspirone HCl (BuSpar)",
"Butorphanol Tartrate (Torbugesic, Torbutrol)",
"Calcitonin",
"Calcitriol (Vitamin D)",
"Calcium Gluconate",
"CAPSTAR (Nitenpyram)",
"Captopril (Capoten)",
"Carbamazepine (Tegretol)",
"Carboplatin (Paraplatin)",
"Carnitine (Carnitor)",
"Carprofen (Rimadyl)",
"Cefadroxil (Cefa-Tabs and Cefa-Drops)",
"Cefazolin (Kefzol, Ancef)",
"Cefixime (Suprax)",
"Cefotaxime (Claforan)",
"Cefotixin (Mefoxin)",
"Cefpodoxime Proxetil (Simplicef)",
"Ceftriaxone (Rocephin)",
"Cephalexin (Keflex)",
"Cephalothin",
"Chlorambucil (Leukeran)",
"Chloramphenicol (Chloromycetin)",
"Chlorhexidine",
"Chlorpheniramine Maleate (Chlor-Trimeton)",
"Chlorpromazine (Thorazine)",
"Cimetidine HCl (Tagamet)",
"Ciprofloxacin (Cipro, Ciloxan)",
"Cisplatin (Platinol-AQ)",
"Colchicine",
"Cyclophosphamide (Cytoxan, Neosar)",
"Cyclosporine (Atopica, Optimmune)",
"Cyclosporine Ophthalmic (Optimmune)",
"Cytarabine",
"Deracoxib (Deramaxx)",
"Derm Caps",
"Desmopressin (DDAVP)",
"Desoxycorticosterone (Percorten-V)",
"Dexamethasone"];
$("#drug_name_1").autocomplete({source:drugs});
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function addTreatment(){
}

function removeTreatment(){
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <input type="button" name="increase" id="increase" value="Increase Drug Treatments" onclick="addTreatment()"/>
  <input type="button" name="decrease" id="decrease" value="Decrease Drug Treatments" onclick="removeTreatment()"/>
</form>
<form id="add_drugs" name="add_drugs" method="post" action="">
    <table width="100%" border="1" name="drug_treatment_table" id="drug_treatment_table">
          <tr>
            <th width="3%" scope="col">#</th>
            <th width="14%" scope="col">Drug</th>
            <th width="32%" scope="col">Special Directions </th>
            <th width="18%" scope="col">Quantity</th>
            <th width="12%" scope="col">How Often</th>
            <th width="8%" scope="col">Starting</th>
            <th width="13%" scope="col">Finishing</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" name="drug_name_1" id="drug_name_1" /></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I don't see why it won't work.  Any ideas?

thanks!
Jon

Comment: i just pasted this code in notepad, saved it as .html and it's working for me.. ?

Comment: What is not working?  It works for me, other than the css missing. http://jsbin.com/eheqih/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look's like it's because of these two script files..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

HTML does not understand script closing tags.. It should be **self closing** ..

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" />
```

Also

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/uwYt4/) .. Its Working fine when you omit the script files..